Audio tag control options are always displayed at last tag
In a page I have multiple audio tags, each tag should display its own download and playback options but the options are always displayed on the last tag.
Need help in displaying options in same control
check the below link and use the below code
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio
<figure>
  <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
  <audio controls src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>
  <a href="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"> Download audio </a>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
  <audio controls src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>
  <a href="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"> Download audio </a>
</figure>
<figure>
  <figcaption>Listen to the T-Rex:</figcaption>
  <audio controls src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"></audio>
  <a href="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3"> Download audio </a>
</figure>


Need help in displaying options in same control
